# Problems with installing Cisco ASDM on a Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, firewall, cisco, java, cisco-asa

I try to get this as short as possible. My company has a computer with the Cisco ASDM-IDM Launcher on it with which we access our Firewall (Type ASA 5505).

Now we want to install the ASDM on our Server so we don't need on every IT-Client computer.

The problem: We can't find an installer for it. An ex-employee installed everything and we can't ask him. After some googling, most said just type the ip in the browser (https://[ip] or https://[ip]/Admin) which didn't work.

Is there a way to install that damn ASDM? Probably useful information:
- ASDM Version: 6.3(1)
- Device Type: ASA 5505
- ASA Version: 8.3(1)
- Java Version: 1.6.0_43
- Operating System: Windows 7 6.1

Comment: are you checked this document (http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/adaptive-security-device-manager/110282-asdm-tshoot.html)

Comment: It would help if you did not simply say "didn't work" but actually explains what exactly occurred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you issue the following commands?

1. Enable the HTTP server for ASDM

   ```
   http server enable
   ```
2. Allow the management host(s) to access ASDM

   ```
   http management_host_ip mask interface_name
   ```

After doing the above in *configuration mode*, access ASDM from Firefox browser (you need to have Java JRE and Java browser plugin installed) using the URL

> https://`<`ASAv IP addr`>`/admin

When you go to this URL, it will download ASDM from the Cisco website to your ASA. It will prompt for the ASAV username and password.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey there. Thanks for your reply :), No I didn't try it with the commands, but I'll try it out and give an answer asap

Comment: Thank you very much. I could install it with your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I always install ASDM by browsing to the firewall and downloading the installer from there. But for this to work, there are a few things that need to be turned on.

Under *Configuration* / *Device Management* / *ASDM/HTTPS/Telnet/SSH*, make sure that you have the ASDM/HTTPS enabled on one the interface you are trying to get to from.

You might run into some issues with Firefox complaining about invalid certificates and the sort, depending on the issue, there are different solutions.

But browsing to https://ciscoasa_ipaddress_or_hostname is indeed a correct way to do this which does work.